# Create page templates using plugins in a php files, With out opening php file, template handle from wp-admin side

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

I want to create page templates in (php) file using wp-dashboard. If I map the template to a parent. Parent should list in the template left side and if i click on the parent from the landing page left side its should display all the templates which i mapped to the parent page.

Anybody could you please help me to do the above scenario using wp-plugin?

Anyone can you please suggest the easiest way to create page template for the above scenario. Its possible please give me some ideas about process of creation of page templates.

Note: The admin user should able to handle the templates and its should not display any code.Once we created a template its should be reusable for template replication. For example if i create 100 landing page in all created landing page left side should display all landing page names , when i click any of the left side page name its should redirect to the corresponding page.

For this Any one can you please suggest plugin or idea to create the process.

Thank you.

Comment: Can't say anything about plugins. I added page template manually. It's pretty easy and fast. But you have to know php at leasta bit, and read about WordPress a bit

Comment: Hi @EugeneAnisiutkin, Thanks for your reply. 

I got a plugin for creating/editing/deleting the page templates in php ."https://wordpress.org/plugins/vstemplate-creator/" this plugin i got from wordpress plugins site. Using that plugin i can do the above mentioned operations. but  for as per my project requirement some customization i made this plugin that's working fine for me.

while creation of template using the plugin working good. 

When am editing and saving  the template using the plugin the page template name 
/**
 * Template Name: faqs-test
 */ getting commented 

this

Comment: After editing while saving the data <?php
/**
 * Template Name: composition-scheme-faqs-test
 */

get_header();

every time this php section getting commented and some times the editor its self its removing the php tag section while switching text to visual editor I will attach the screen shot for the refference.

Comment: Glad you found a solution that suits you. I used manual adding myself, but i needed a singe template for a specific theme.

Comment: For me around above 100 pages is there in my website. For creating files its will take time. to avoiding that am searching for the plugin like "wordpress.org/plugins/vstemplate-creator" this. but unfortunatly its not getting a 100% of clarity as per my requirement after customizing a plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the Elementor Page Builder Plugin, As you want to create the Page Template using with a plugin.

Create a Custom Page Template Plugin URL: [Add Custom Page Template](https://wordpress.org/plugins/add-custom-page-template/)

Hope!! It will work!

Comment: Hi priyanka, Thanks for your reply. Its possible to for as per my requirement to create the page ? 

page have 3 sections 1-left menu ,2-middle content section, 3-contact form 

in left menu should list all templates which i have created with parent and child.

the form should be customized the form action should be my action url. 

and once i created its should be duplicate pages .

is it possible with elementor page builder ? 

the above following things i want to do. for that purpose need to buy the plugin/ free plugin is enough to do ?

Comment: yes, it's possible to create the page as your requirement. you go through the plugin documentation and demo. so, you can get the more idea on same.

Comment: if i want to list all landing pages dynamically that's possible?

Comment: it's available in paid version or free version ?

Comment: https://wordpress.org/plugins/add-custom-page-template/#description this following plugin its listing the templates , not able to edit/ delete the template files .

Comment: you have to check it on same. it will be paid version for some extra functionality. so, you cannot access some other options in the plugin